# Unable to run puppeteer getting REQUEST Errors parent

Tags: node.js, npm, puppeteer

Here is the error I am getting:

```
MODULE 128: Module._load REQUEST ./Errors parent: /crawler/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js
MODULE 128: RELATIVE: requested: ./Errors from parent.id /crawler/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js
MODULE 128: load "/crawler/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Errors.js" for module "/crawler/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Errors.js"
MODULE 128: Module._load REQUEST ./Errors parent: /crawler/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/LifecycleWatcher.js
MODULE 128: Module._load REQUEST ./Errors parent: /crawler/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js
MODULE 128: Module._load REQUEST ./Errors parent: /crawler/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js
MODULE 128: Module._load REQUEST ./Errors parent: /crawler/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Puppeteer.js
MODULE 128: Module._load REQUEST ./Errors parent: /crawler/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/api.js
```

Source code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://buddy.works');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'buddy-screenshot.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "2.0.0"
  }
}
```

So what are those errors? And how can I get puppeteer to work?

node version:
v13.6.0

npm version:
6.13.4

**UPDATE**

When I execute, at the end of the logs it shows this (there is more information):

```
NET 32: pipe false undefined
HTTP 32: outgoing message end.
(node:32) Warning: Setting the NODE_DEBUG environment variable to 'http' can expose sensitive data (such as passwords, tokens and authentication headers) in the resulting log.
NET 32: _read
NET 32: _read wait for connection
```

But it just suspends there.

**UPDATE 2**

I was wrong it throws this after a while.

```
NET 32: afterConnect
NET 32: destroy
NET 32: close
NET 32: close handle
HTTP 32: SOCKET ERROR: connect ETIMEDOUT 127.0.0.1:34435 Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 127.0.0.1:34435
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16)
(node:32) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<ErrorEvent>
(node:32) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:32) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
NET 32: emit close
HTTP 32: HTTP socket close
NET 32: destroy
NET 32: close
NET 32: close handle
NET 32: destroy
NET 32: close
NET 32: close handle
NET 32: emit close
NET 32: emit close
NET 32: destroy
NET 32: close
NET 32: close handle
NET 32: emit close
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
NET 134: _read
NET 134: Socket._handle.readStart
NET 134: _read
NET 134: Socket._handle.readStart
NET 134: _read
NET 134: _read
NET 134: createConnection [
  {
    protocolVersion: 13,
    maxPayload: 268435456,
    perMessageDeflate: false,
    followRedirects: false,
    maxRedirects: 10,
    createConnection: [Function: netConnect],
    socketPath: undefined,
    hostname: undefined,
    protocol: undefined,
    timeout: undefined,
    method: undefined,
    auth: undefined,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    path: undefined,
    port: '35845',
    defaultPort: 80,
    headers: {
      'Sec-WebSocket-Version': 13,
      'Sec-WebSocket-Key': 'e+5Y3wgF2dyBGe4U9aTUOg==',
      Connection: 'Upgrade',
      Upgrade: 'websocket'
    }
  },
  null,
  [Symbol(normalizedArgs)]: true
]
```

Comment: These seems to be logs. if you run your code with `NODE_DEBUG=module node your-code.js` you'll get these logs which basically shows what modules are being loaded. do you get any errors beside these logs?

Comment: @mbit When I execute the code I get what I just added to my question. It just suspends there. Is there any other details you might need?

Comment: @mbit I tried https://google.ca with the same result.

Comment: these are node logs not errors (beside that socket error), seems to me you've set `NODE_DEBUG`, try unsetting debug mode using `unset NODE_DEBUG` see if the logs get removed.